# Oracle PL/SQL script optimization for setting one record value to another

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am fairly new to SQL scripting and especially Oracle SQL scripting. I have a task where I need to get the most recent record in a table and change the date attribute to a previous date.

```
Cycle_ID    Extract_DATE
========    ============
119         26-NOV-12
120         03-DEC-12
```

So to reiterate, I would like to set the Extract_DATE for Cycle_ID 120 to the Extract_DATE of Cycle_ID 119.

Here is the script that I am using to accomplish this.

```
update <table_name>  
set extract_date = (SELECT EXTRACT_DATE 
                   from <table_name> 
                   group by cycle_counter_id, extract_date 
                   having cycle_counter_id=(select max(cycle_counter_id)-1 from <table_name>)) 
where cycle_counter_id = (SELECT CYCLE_COUNTER_ID
                          from <table_name> 
                           group by cycle_counter_id
                           having cycle_counter_id=(select max(cycle_counter_id) from <table_name>));
```

My question is, how can I simplify this script and/or make it cleaner or more efficient?

Comment: It's a single SQL statement (which is pretty simple). I'm not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I give you works, **IF AND ONLY IF**, the column **cycle_id** is the **primary key** of your table.

```
UPDATE pl_updatetest t1
SET t1.extract_date = 
(
    SELECT t2.extract_date
    FROM pl_updatetest t2
    WHERE t1.cycle_id = t2.cycle_id + 1
)
WHERE t1.cycle_id <> (SELECT MIN(cycle_id) FROM pl_updatetest);
```

Here is a test cast indicating how this query can be used to change your table.

```
DROP TABLE pl_updatetest;
CREATE TABLE pl_updatetest
(
    cycle_id        NUMBER      NOT NULL,
    extract_date    DATE        NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE pl_updatetest ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PL_UPDATETEST
    PRIMARY KEY(cycle_id);

INSERT ALL
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(100, TO_DATE('01-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(101, TO_DATE('02-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(102, TO_DATE('03-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(103, TO_DATE('04-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(104, TO_DATE('05-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
    INTO pl_updatetest(cycle_id, extract_date) 
        VALUES(105, TO_DATE('06-JAN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
SELECT * FROM DUAL;

Table dropped.


Table created.


Table altered.


6 rows created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM pl_updatetest;

  CYCLE_ID EXTRACT_D
---------- ---------
   100     01-JAN-12
   101     02-JAN-12
   102     03-JAN-12
   103     04-JAN-12
   104     05-JAN-12
   105     06-JAN-12

6 rows selected.

SQL> 

UPDATE pl_updatetest t1
SET t1.extract_date = 
(
    SELECT t2.extract_date
    FROM pl_updatetest t2
    WHERE t1.cycle_id = t2.cycle_id + 1
)
WHERE t1.cycle_id <> (SELECT MIN(cycle_id) FROM pl_updatetest);

5 rows updated.

SQL> 
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM pl_updatetest;
CYCLE_ID    EXTRACT_D
---------- -----------
 100       01-JAN-12
 101       01-JAN-12
 102       02-JAN-12
 103       03-JAN-12
 104       04-JAN-12
 105       05-JAN-12

 6 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

Regards

Dariyoosh

Comment: It's not quite as simple as you make out, you've assumed that thePK is an incrementing integer with no gaps. It's highly unlikely that this is the case...

Comment: It doesn't appear to be changing anything in the table I'm using.  I can't pinpoint the logic but it said all 120 rows updated but I'm not seeing any difference.